# Function gets executed for every previous element aswell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contextmenu

I am currently creating a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/yoXNOQ), where you can change the color,background-color,text,... of each element on the page when opening the contextmenu.
I store the element, which I right-clicked in a variable:

```
var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    efp = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

When I return the value of that variable `efp` in the console, it returns me the correct element.

---

Now the problem:
Changing the color of, for example a text element, works fine. But when I try to do that another time, it not only changes the element, but the element I previously changed aswell.
*Something like this:*
Change color of `p` -> changes `p`

Change background of `section` -> changes `section` *AND* `p`
Change color of `h1` -> changes `h1` *AND* `section` *AND* `p`

---

And here's my full code:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e){
  $('.custom-menu li').show(0);
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = e.target.nodeName;
  var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
      efp = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  console.log(efp);
  switch(el){
    case "P":
      ctxP();
      break;
    case "CONTENT":
      ctxCon();
      break;
    case "HEADER":
      ctxHead();
      break;
    case "FOOTER":
      ctxFoot();
      break;
  }
  $(".custom-menu li").on("click", function(){
    switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
      case "color": 
        colorPick();
        break;
      case "bgcolor": 
        bgcolorPick();
        break;
      case "text": 
        textChange();
        break;
    }
    $(".custom-menu").fadeOut(100);
  });
  $(".custom-menu").finish().fadeIn(100).css({
    top: e.pageY + "px",
    left: e.pageX + "px"
  });
  function ctxP(){
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=bgcolor]').hide();
  }
  function ctxCon(){
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
  }
  function ctxHead(){
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
  }
  function ctxFoot(){
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
    $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
  }
  function colorPick(){
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".colorpicker").fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
    $(".color").click(function(){
      var color = $(this).css('background-color');
      $(efp).css('color', color);
      $(".colorpicker, .overlay").fadeOut();
    });
  }
  function bgcolorPick(){
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".colorpicker").fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
    $(".color").click(function(){
      var color = $(this).css('background-color');
      $(efp).css('background-color', color);
      $(".colorpicker, .overlay").fadeOut();
    });
  }
  function textChange(){
    $(".overlay, .textChange").fadeIn();
    $('.textChange input').keypress(function(e) {
      var text = $(this).val();
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $(efp).text(text);
        $(".overlay, .textChange").fadeOut();
        $(this).val("");
      }
    });
  }
});

$(document).click(function(e){    
  if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
    $(".custom-menu").fadeOut(100);
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header,content,footer{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  padding:50px 20%;
}
header{
  background:#efefef;
}
content{
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
footer{
  background-color:#afafaf
}

.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
}
.custom-menu li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  user-select: none;
}
.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DEF;
}
.colorpicker{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:20;
  display:flex;
  display:none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  height:80%;
  width:80%;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.color{
  display:block;
  flex-grow:1;
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.textChange{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:20;
  top:calc(50% - 25px);
  width:20%;
  height:50px;
  left:40%;
}
.textChange input{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:1.1em;
}
.overlay{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:10;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;
  opacity:.5;
  top:0;
}
.disabled{
  pointer-events:none;
  color:#a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <header><p>Hello</p></header>
  <content><p>Peter</p></content>
  <footer><p>Hallo</p></footer>
</div>


<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="textChange">
  <input type="textarea" placeholder="Type new text in here">
</div>

<div class="colorpicker">
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#1abc9c"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#16a085"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2ecc71"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#27ae60"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#3498db"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2980b9"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#9b59b6"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#8e44ad"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#e74c3c"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#c0392b"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#e67e22"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#d35400"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#f1c40f"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#f39c12"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#ecf0f1"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#bdc3c7"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#95a5a6"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#7f8c8d"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#34495e"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2c3e50"></div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="color">change color</li>
  <li data-action="bgcolor">change background-color</li>
  <li data-action="text">change text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Share codepen please

Comment: @MichaelKapustey provided snippet seems to show the problem to me

Comment: @MichaelKapustey It's literally the same like the SO snippet, but I linked it in the first line :)

Comment: Why are `ctxCon()`, `ctxHead()` and `ctxFoot()` three times the exact same function, and there is a `switch` statement to choose which of them should execute? O_o

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorry, that may looks weird :D But that's for future purposes, when I probably add more options to the context menu. So every element got "its own" context menu.

Comment: @WhoeverVotedToCloseThisQuestion Could you please tell me why, so I can improve my way to ask questions on SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of this line :

```
$(".color").click( function(){
```

Every time the `bgcolorPick()` function is called, you attach one more click handler. So every time you click, all your click handlers execute on all the elements previously clicked, changing their colour. Detach the click handler before attaching it again to the latest clicked element :

```
$(".color").off("click").on("click", function(){
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/xLPNoe)

Comment: You're a god. Thank you so much!

Comment: The only thing, that doesn't work now is changing multiple texts. So like last time it works for the first time, but not the second time. I hoped that answer solved that aswell. But I guess I gonna figure out, where the problem is :)

Comment: Have a look at @Nathan's answer then, it may help

Comment: That's bad. Subscribing outside is much better in case of performance

Comment: @MichaelKapustey I agree, this code can be vastly optimized, but that's not quite the subject here. We're just trying to make it work, not to refactor it.

Comment: Update: With Nathan's method, somehow it changed the `background-color` aswell when changing the `color`. So I used your method @JeremyThille . The problem with the text, I solved like this: When clicking "change text", it adds the attribute `contenteditable` to the element and on focusout it removes it. Everything working like a charm now. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a closure and attaching a new `click` listener on every right click within the `on('contextmenu'` event listener, hence this behavior. Simply move all of your declarations out of the event listener like this :

```js
function ctxP() {
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=bgcolor]').hide();
}

function ctxCon() {
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
}

function ctxHead() {
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
}

function ctxFoot() {
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=color]').hide();
  $('.custom-menu li[data-action=text]').hide();
}

function colorPick() {
  $(".overlay").fadeIn();
  $(".colorpicker").fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
  $(".color").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(efp).css('color', color);
    $(".colorpicker, .overlay").fadeOut();
  });
}

function bgcolorPick() {
  $(".overlay").fadeIn();
  $(".colorpicker").fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
  $(".color").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(efp).css('background-color', color);
    $(".colorpicker, .overlay").fadeOut();
  });
}

function textChange() {
  $(".overlay, .textChange").fadeIn();
  $('.textChange input').keypress(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(emo).text(text);
      $(".overlay, .textChange").fadeOut();
      $(this).val("");
    }
  });
}

$(".custom-menu li").on("click", function() {
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    case "color":
      colorPick();
      break;
    case "bgcolor":
      bgcolorPick();
      break;
    case "text":
      textChange();
      break;
  }

  $(".custom-menu").fadeOut(100);
});

var efp;

$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.custom-menu li').show(0);

  var el = e.target.nodeName,
    x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
  
  efp = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

  $(".custom-menu").finish().fadeIn(100).css({
    top: e.pageY + "px",
    left: e.pageX + "px"
  });

  switch (el) {
    case "P":
      ctxP();
      break;
    case "CONTENT":
      ctxCon();
      break;
    case "HEADER":
      ctxHead();
      break;
    case "FOOTER":
      ctxFoot();
      break;
  }
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
    $(".custom-menu").fadeOut(100);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
content,
footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px 20%;
}

header {
  background: #efefef;
}

content {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

footer {
  background-color: #afafaf
}

.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DEF;
}

.colorpicker {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  display: flex;
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.color {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textChange {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 40%;
}

.textChange input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  top: 0;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </header>
  <content>
    <p>Peter</p>
  </content>
  <footer>
    <p>Hallo</p>
  </footer>
</div>


<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="textChange">
  <input type="textarea" placeholder="Type new text in here">
</div>

<div class="colorpicker">
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#1abc9c"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#16a085"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2ecc71"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#27ae60"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#3498db"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2980b9"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#9b59b6"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#8e44ad"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#e74c3c"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#c0392b"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#e67e22"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#d35400"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#f1c40f"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#f39c12"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#ecf0f1"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#bdc3c7"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#95a5a6"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#7f8c8d"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#34495e"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color:#2c3e50"></div>
</div>

<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="color">change color</li>
  <li data-action="bgcolor">change background-color</li>
  <li data-action="text">change text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you aswell! But I had to accept Jeremy's answer because he was first. Sorry :/

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) @JeremyThille I already upvoted you.